# magento visitor logs

Tags: magento, logging, models

Is there a way to access the user logs in Magento? I know the database has a table called `log_visitor` that can see logs visitors, and `log_visitor_info` logs more info about the visitors (IP, user agent). How do I get to that data? When I write

```
$visitors = Mage::getModel('log/visitor')->getCollection()
foreach ($visitors as $visitor)  {
    print_r($visitor->getData());
}
```

I get an error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Recoverable Error: Method Varien_Db_Select::__toString() must return a string value  in /path/to/server/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 272' in /path/to/server/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:239`

Comment: Have you tried `debug()` in place of `getData()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the direct database query if you're not sure about object's API.

For example

```
      $read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');

      $results = $read->fetchAll("select * from log_visitor_info");

      foreach($resulst as $res)
        echo $res['http_referer'] . " - " . $res['http_user_agent'] . " - " . $res['remote_addr'] . " - ";
```

Comment: Watch out with doing direct db queries. Magento's db is riddled with private keys and everything else you can imagine. I'm not saying this answer is bad in any way, but I have yet to find the need to use a DB query that cannot be accomplished using Magento's EAV model

Answer (score 3):

You need to use var_dump or var_export on php objects.

The following code will output each visitor object:

```
$visitors = Mage::getModel('log/visitor')->getCollection();

foreach ($visitors as $visitor) {
        var_dump($visitor);
}
```