# Receiving "Query was empty" error when loading log visitor collection in Magento

Tags: magento, logging, collections, model, visitor-pattern

How does one retrieve a collection of visitors using the Log/Visitor model? I've tried using the following code....

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',TRUE);
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
require_once $root.'/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');

$visitors = Mage::getModel('log/visitor')->getCollection()->load();
?>
```

But it returns an error, an excerpt from which is...

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty
```

The query doesn't throw any errors until I add the 'load()' method to the chain. My question is similar to [magento visitor logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147564/magento-visitor-logs), but that code example was missing the load() and the only answer resorted to using the resource model directly, which I don't think should be necessary.

Update:

Magento version being used is 1.4.1.1. Full exception trace:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty' in /home/dev_fluid/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234 Stack trace: #0 /home/dev_fluid/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #1 /home/dev_fluid/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(468): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #2 /home/dev_fluid/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('', Array) #3 /home/dev_fluid/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(333): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('', Array) #4 /home/dev_fluid/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(706): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array) #5 /home/dev_fluid/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(707): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array) #6 /home/dev_fluid/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(620): Varien_Data_Collect in /home/dev_fluid/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 234

New trace, using's Jurgen's getTraceAsString() approach:

```
#0 /home/dev_fluid/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) 
#1 /home/dev_fluid/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(468): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) 
#2 /home/dev_fluid/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('', Array) 
#3 /home/dev_fluid/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(333): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('', Array) 
#4 /home/dev_fluid/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(706): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array) 
#5 /home/dev_fluid/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(707): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array) 
#6 /home/dev_fluid/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(620): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll(Object(Varien_Db_Select)) 
#7 /home/dev_fluid/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(590): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->getData() 
#8 /home/dev_fluid/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Mysql4/Visitor/Collection.php(300): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load(false, false) 
#9 /home/dev_fluid/public_html/andy/visitor.php(11): Mage_Log_Model_Mysql4_Visitor_Collection->load() 
#10 {main}
```

Comment: Your code to retrieve a visitor collection should work without problems. Posting the exception trace and the Magento version used may be helpful here.

Comment: The expection trace you posted is incomplete; the whole bootstrap is missing ({main}, etc).

Comment: Hi Jurgen - Forgive my ignorance, but how do a generate the relevant debug info? I've currently got display errors on, developer mode on and errors/local.xml file set up.

Comment: Usually what you have enabled is enough to get exception traces. It looks like you copy/pasted it incompletely or it got cut off somehow. The last three lines of a Magento trace usually contain `Mage.php`, `index.php` and `{main}`. Yours doesn't. So we cannot follow the process flow the issue takes. Have a look at e.g. [http://stackoverflow.com/q/10907649/693207](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10907649/693207) to see how a full trace usually looks like.

Comment: Hi @Jürgen Thelen - I don't know why the trace I'm getting isn't in the usual format. I even tried catching the error and using `echo Varien_Debug::backtrace(true, true);` but just blank. I think I might have to give up?!

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code to:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',TRUE);
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
require_once $root.'/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');

$visitors = Mage::getModel('log/visitor')->getCollection();
try {
    $x = $visitors->load();
    die('no exception');
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());
}
```

If the exception occurs within the `load()` method, this should give you a full trace.

If that trace doesn't help you to pin down the issue, I'd recommend to use a PHP debugger like xdebug, or Zend Debug, or DBG, etc. (depending on what debugger your IDE supports).

Setting a breakpoint right before the `load()` method and single stepping thru the code should show give you a clue, why the query is empty.

Comment: I have a very similar issue as the OP - I get the same "Query is Empty" error in ./var/report/number in my custom extension controller but I pasted your sample code to test.php in the magento root and replaced it with my query - it works fine. Any ideas?